# a macro for putting accent underneath

Tags: macros, accents

I've copied a macro sequence from *The Advanced TEXbook*, p. 446. It supposed to put the accent#1 under the character#2.

```
\def\subaccent#1#2{\leavevmode\vtop{\setbox0=\hbox{#2}
\copy0\nointerlineskip\hbox to\wd0{\hss\char#1\hss}}}
```

I put the code into a self-written subaccent.sty file, then \usepackage{subaccent} in the preamble.

However, while calling the macro with \subaccent, the following error occurred:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\hss
```

I'm compiling with Lualatex. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this macro?

Comment: You can just use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\underset`: `$\underset{\text{a}}{\text{b}}$`

Comment: The `accents` package has `\underaccent{<accent>}{<character>}`

Comment: `\underaccent` would definitely be preferable to `\underset` in this case.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: True.

Comment: @Werner This is not for math.

Comment: Remove `\char`: otherwise `#1` should be a number, not a character.

Comment: BTW, `\setbox0=\hbox{#2}` should be `\sbox0{#2}` for the case `#2` contains `\color`, whose reset color command would leak out of the box at the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro expects `#1` to be a number. I suggest a modification based on my suspicion that you need it for undersetting a bar to a letter.

```
\documentclass[12pt, b5paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Calluna}

\newcommand{\ppacute}[1]{\accent"00B4 #1}
\newcommand{\ppbarunder}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \setbox2=\vtop{
    \copy0
    \nointerlineskip
    \kern.1ex
    \hbox to\wd0{\hss\char"AF\hss}
  }%
  \dimen0=\dp0 \advance\dimen0 .25ex
  \dp2=\dimen0
  \leavevmode\box2
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt

aha\ppacute{m}tattva, rúpa, tanmátra

\ppacute{t} \ppbarunder{n} 
\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt
\fbox{\ppbarunder{n}}
\fbox{\ppbarunder{g}}

\end{document}
```

The modification is necessary to remove the depth added by the fact that the character U+00AF has a height.

The two `\fbox` commands, together with the strange settings to `\fboxrule` and `\fboxsep`, are meant to show that the depth is set accurately.

[image]

If I add the code

```
\newcommand{\pphatunder}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \setbox2=\vtop{
    \copy0
    \nointerlineskip
    \kern0.05ex
    \hbox to\wd0{\hss\char"2C6\hss}
  }%
  \dimen0=\dp0 \advance\dimen0 .45ex
  \dp2=\dimen0
  \leavevmode\box2
  \endgroup
}
```

Then the input

```
\pphatunder{n}
\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt
\fbox{\pphatunder{n}}
\fbox{\pphatunder{g}}
```

produces

[image]

The character U+02C6 is MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT.

Comment: Grazie mille @egreg! I would like to put ^ (actually it should be smaller, a circumflex) underneath n. But circumflex is not within the 128 characters of TeX character table, as far as I know. Any solution?

Comment: @Roshnii Does the addition seem good?

Comment: It works perfectly! Grazie mille mille!